# In ASP.NET Core MVC, I have multiple forms on a page, and the validation summaries show on both forms

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, umbraco

If I have two forms on a page, and submit one the same validation summary shows for both.

I am using an Umbraco 10 `SurfaceController` but I don't know that this is relevant.

The controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateUmbracoFormRouteString]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginForm model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Please provide username and password");
        return CurrentUmbracoPage();
    }
    //...snipped...
}
```

The validation summary looks like this

```
@Html.ValidationSummary()
```

I have another similar form for registration and the registration validation shows in the header login area when I submit that form.

I looked into the 'prefix' parameter but I failed to find any documentation regarding it's use.

Answer (score 1):

`@Html.ValidationSummary()` just generates IHtmlContent accroding to your ModelState error,it doesn't know which form you posted at all

In order to decide where  the error message should be rendered,you could add a hidden input pass a value related the form to controller

For Example,I tried with a minimal example as below:

```
public class Entity1
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string? Prop1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Entity2
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string? Prop2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyViewModel
    {
        public Entity1? Entity1 { get; set; }
        public Entity2? Entity2 { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            @if (ViewData["Form"] as string == "form1")
            {
                @Html.ValidationSummary()
            }
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Entity1.Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Entity1.Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Entity1.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Entity1.Prop1" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Entity1.Prop1" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Entity1.Prop1" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <input name="form" value="form1" hidden />
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
        <form asp-action="Create" name="">
            @if (ViewData["Form"] as string == "form2")
            {
                @Html.ValidationSummary()
            }
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Entity2.Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Entity2.Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Entity2.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Entity2.Prop2" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Entity2.Prop2" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Entity2.Prop2" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <input name="form" value="form2" hidden />
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(MyViewModel myvm)
    {
        .......
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "ModelErr");
        var formname = HttpContext.Request.Form["form"].ToString();
        ViewData["Form"] = formname;
        return View(myvm);
    }
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: This does do what I asked so that is helpful, I also get cross-contamination of individual asp-validation-for properties, and I could wrap all those with the same condition or make a custom version... but I think I'll just name them so they are unique.

It's a shame there is no built-in solution to deal with this.